# how deep linking can redirect the user to google play?

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink, android-deep-link

I don't understand how deep linking can redirect the user to google play? example if I gave to the user the URL: myApp://launch how the user could be redirected to the google play if he doesn't have my app installed?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible with myapp:// schema, you will have to use an HTTP schema to hit a webserver that resolves to a HTTP redirect to Play Store.
Or you can try tools like [Branch](https://docs.branch.io/links/integrate/) to achieve this functionality.

Comment: but the question is, how Branch do the job ?

Comment: I have already explained that in the answer. If you don't want to setup your own server for redirecting, use Branch.